# "to pine away from"

Tags: meaning, verbs

[Definition 1.1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pine?q=pine#pine-2) states:

> Suffer a mental and physical decline, especially because of a broken heart

Yet what does "pine away from" mean? Does it equal "to pine from" = to suffer from? 
Is the **away** optional, such as as follows?

> [P182, Dialogues and Essays
>    By Seneca :](http://books.google.com/books?id=nSDpoK635v8C&pg=PA182&dq=%22pine+away+from%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CVOlU52DAsqpkQWCxoHIDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22pine%20away%20from%22&f=false)
>
> Accordingly, it is not open to you to claim your female sex as an excuse for persistent grief, as your own excellent qualities make you stranger to this; you should be as far removed from the tears, as from the vices, of women. Not even women will permit you **to pine away from** your wound, but will tell you to make a swift end of necessary grief before rising with a lighter heart, if only you are prepared to contemplate those women whose evident courage has won them a place in the ranks of great men.

Comment: _Away_ here has the same meaning as in _fade away_, i.e., pining until you become diminished, reduced, to nothingness. _From_ is indeed as in _suffer from_: it indicates the cause of the pining.

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pine+away

Comment: The word *pine* has different aspects to it. On the other hand, *to pine for* and *to pine away* are idioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To pine" is an idiom meaning "to long for, to desire from afar, often without hope of reciprocation."

"To pine away" is an idiom meaning "to waste, decline, diminish." In this case, the "from" indicated the cause of the pining away. The sense is related, but not the same. In the quote you provided, the "away" is not optional.